# rail+devise+devise-google-oauth redirect to google login when visit restricted url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, oauth-2.0

I'm using Devise with omniauth-google-oauth2 gem.
I only want to implement google sign_in.
This is my user model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:google_oauth2]
  attr_accessible :email

  def self.find_for_google_oauth2(access_token, signed_in_resource=nil)
    data = access_token.info
    user = User.where(:email => data["email"]).first
    unless user
      user = User.create(email: data["email"] )
    end
    user
  end
end
```

routes file:

```
#config/routes.rb
Booking::Application.routes.draw do
  #https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview#using-omniauth-without-other-authentications
  devise_for :users , controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"}
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'sign_in', :to => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    get 'sign_out', :to => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end

  resources :events
end
```

according with official docs I have this line in my events_controller.rb

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```

Problem:
If i visit events/new the app want to redirect me in /sign_in and this is the error:

```
Started GET "/events/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-04 20:50:56 +0100
Processing by EventsController#new as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms


Started GET "/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-04 20:50:56 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered /home/cristiano/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@booking/gems/devise-3.2.2/app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (13.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `session_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f42ecc695b8>:0x007f42ecc65b98>):
    1: <h2>Sign in</h2>
    2: 
    3: <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    4:   <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
    5:   <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>
    6:
```

I want to redirect the user in the user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) url and not in the sign_path url becouse i only use the google login and i have no local sign_in/sign_up

***SOLUTION:***

copy all views to my application:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Edit app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb removing all contents and appendig the link to google authentication:

```
#app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb
<%= link_to "Sign in with Google", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2) %>
```

Thanks to [gregates](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1619796/gregates)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It's simple and produces the desired outcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So sending to the `new_user_session_path` or the `root_path` if that's undefined is built into the devise failure app. If you want to change this behavior, you'll need to customize that app. Here is a somewhat old but still relevant guide to customizing this behavior by using a custom failure app: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated

However, in my opinion you should create a custom view at the `new_user_session_path` (i.e., `app/views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb` that prompts your user to sign in with google, rather than simply automatically signing them in. If you just send them to the `user_omniauth_authorize_path(:google_oauth2)` AND they've already authorized your app AND they have a current google session, then they'll just be automatically signed in with no prompt, which to me is bad UX.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very old, but maybe someone can come with the same problem, like me, ;-). This will redirect the not logged user to the google new session page directly

#### app/models/user.rb

```
devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[google_oauth2]
```

#### app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    redirect_to user_google_oauth2_omniauth_authorize_url
  end
end
```

#### config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.omniauth :google_oauth2, 'google_oauth2_api_key', 'google_oauth2_api_secret'
```

#### config/routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'callbacks' }
devise_scope :user do
  root 'sessions#new'
  get 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
  get '/users/sign_in', to: 'sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
  post '/users/sign_in', to: 'devise/sessions#create', as: :user_session
  get '/users/sign_out', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
end
```

#### app/controllers/callbacks_controller.rb

```
class CallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def oauth_callback
    user = get_user_and_do_what_you_need_with_the_oaut_response
    sign_in_and_redirect user
  end
```

This is going to produce the behavior that @gregates consider bad UX